# Database: Transaction isolation levels automatically determine placement of locks?

Tags: database, transactions, locking, isolation-level

I just started to know more about transactions, locks and isolation levels. I'm getting a little confused here and trying to get some clarification.

I had referred to these pages for more understanding:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29)

My question here is:
Does the transaction isolation levels **automatically** determine when database tables and/or rows will be placed and when these locks will be unlocked?

Comment: what do you mean by 'automatically '?

Comment: since locks can be inserted manually in our sql statements. so in the case of transaction isolation levels, does the sql engine add the locks in for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the database handles the locking for you and the ramifications of those locks based upon the isolation level. As a developer, you need to be aware of how the isolation levels impact locks, data availability, data state and data visibility within the database.

But fundamentally, it is the DB service itself which manages these aspects. You don't need to do any kinds of manual locking, for example.